# Hung process and Linux syscall 248?

Tags: linux, system-calls, freeze

I'm troubleshooting a hung self test for the upcoming OpenSSL 1.1.0 on a particular machine. I've tried to debug this issue twice, and it resulted in two unresponsive GDB's and two hung processes:

```
$ ps -A | grep afalgtest
1030 pts/0    00:00:00 afalgtest
1196 pts/0    00:00:00 afalgtest
```

I was able to kill GDB, but I was not able to kill the hung processes.

According to `/proc/<pid>/syscall`, both are in syscall 248:

```
via:test$ sudo cat /proc/1030/syscall 
248 0xb7fd6000 0x1 0xbfff98d4 0xb7fb9270 0xbfff98e0 0xb7ec45f7 0xbfff986c 0xb7fdbbe8
via:test$ sudo cat /proc/1196/syscall 
248 0xb7fd6000 0x1 0xbfff98d4 0xb7fb9270 0xbfff98e0 0xb7ec45f7 0xbfff986c 0xb7fdbbe8
```

I'm running a machine with the VIA C7-D processor, and it needs Lubuntu 15 because its one of the few distros to support VIA's PM400 graphics chipset. Lubuntu 15 uses the 4.2 kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux via 4.2.0-30-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 00:57:19 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

The next step is:

```
$ cat /usr/include/asm-generic/unistd.h | grep 248
$
```

Which returns nothing. Next, cat'ing `unistd.h`:

```
...
/*
 * Architectures may provide up to 16 syscalls of their own
 * starting with this value.
 */
#define __NR_arch_specific_syscall 244

#define __NR_wait4 260
__SC_COMP(__NR_wait4, sys_wait4, compat_sys_wait4)
#define __NR_prlimit64 261
__SYSCALL(__NR_prlimit64, sys_prlimit64)
#define __NR_fanotify_init 262
__SYSCALL(__NR_fanotify_init, sys_fanotify_init)
#define __NR_fanotify_mark 263
...
```

Just in case `248` is `0x248`:

```
$ cat /usr/include/asm-generic/unistd.h | grep 584
$
```

So my question is, how can I determine which syscall the process is hung in?

---

It appears I have the latest kernel headers:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-4.2.0-30-generic is already the newest version.
linux-headers-4.2.0-30-generic set to manually installed.
```

Comment: Try `xmllint --xpath '/syscalls_info/syscall[@number=248]' /usr/share/gdb/syscalls/i386-linux.xml`

Answer (score 1):

The syscall number is decimal. Syscall table you are looking for can be found in arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl. Regardless, you are inspecting the wrong file. What you want to see is the entire backtrace provided in /stack file. The kernel is nice enough to not only unwind the stack but also resolve all symbols. Alternatively you can use a debugger (named crash) to inspect the live kernel.